# 'The cabinet file media1.cab required for this installation is corrupted and cannot be used ' in dowloading Node.js

Tags: node.js, windows-installer

I use Window 11. I installed Node.js a few years ago, then uninstalled it not long ago. I now want to reinstall it on my computer.
But during installation an error occurs while copying new files:

```
The cabinet file 'media1.cab' required for this installation is corrupted and cannot be used. This could indicate a network error, an error reading for CD-ROM, or a problem with this package.
```

I tried deleting temporary files.
I also turned the computer off and on again.
I checked that the uninstallation was successful (I uninstalled using Revo Uninstaller).
I check that the program is installed on "Program Files" folder, and not "Program Files (X86)" folder
But nothing helped

How I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Third party uninstallers are notorious for deleting portions of the package registration corrupting the machine state. That creates problems much like you describe.

You won't like this but my recommendation when getting into this situation is to reformat your computer and start over. Then don't use any third party "Windows cleaners" to corrupt your computer state.